# Uniform and Chi-square distributions

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am trying to solve this problem:

Let $X \sim U[0,1]$. Then $Y = -2\log X$ is $\chi$-square distribution with parameter $2$.

I proceeded this way,

$$P(Y \leq y) = P(-2\log X \leq y) = P(X \leq \exp(-y/2))$$

$$F_X(x) = \frac{x-a}{b-a},\quad a \leq x <b$$

$$\Rightarrow F_X(\exp(-y/2)) = \exp(-y/2),\quad 0 \leq x <1.$$

Now I found the PDF:

$$f(y) = -1/2\exp(-y/2)$$

But the $\chi$-square PDF with parameter $2$ is given by

$$f(y) = 1/2\exp(-y/2)$$

I am not sure why I get the negative sign. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: $P\left[-2\ln X\leq y\right]=P\left[X\geq e^{-\frac{y}{2}}\right]$
(dividing by negative $-2$ so switch from $\leq$ to $\geq$)

Answer (score 1):

the negative sign will be canceled because we have to the absolute value of the derivative according to The Jacobian in one-to-one transformation technique.